# HTML inline elements and vertical/horizontal margins

Tags: html, css, dom, margin

In the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dddaaLwL/ you can see that horizontal margins have an effect on the inline elements. and vertical margins do not have an effect. Is this right? why so?

```
#s1 {
margin-left: 40px;
}
#s2 {
margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your fiddle is correct. why?

> An inline element occupies only the space bounded by the tags that
>   define the inline element.

More info **[HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente)**

---

Examples of **Inline Elements**:

`<a>`,`<span>`,`<b>`,`<em>`,`<i>`,`<cite>`,`<mark>`, and `<code>`

More about **Inline Elements**

An inline element has, but may not be limited to, the following characteristics:

- Flows along with text content, thus
- Will not clear previous content to drop to the next line like block
  elements Is subject to white-space settings in CSS
- Will ignore top and bottom margin settings, but will apply left and
  right margins, and any padding
- Will ignore the width and height properties
- If floated left or right, will automatically become a block-level
  element, subject to all block characteristics
- Is subject to the vertical-align property

More info [**HERE**](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/)

Comment: Thanks...can you share the url where you found the pointers, remember reading this somewhere!

Comment: All my sources are in my answers , just click where says "here".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, vertical margins do have an effect on inline elements, but because the element above it isn't a block, it's actually using the margin from the top of the page instead of the previous element. Let's take a quick look at the box model:

[image: Box Model Image]

Because `inline` elements don't handle bounding in the same way that `block` type elements do. They can only hold data, and other inline elements, and they follow the constraints of the parent element, and only exert influence over their individual space.

However, if they were `inline-block` elements, you'd see a different result:

[image: Inline Block Box Model]

As you can see, `inline-block` elements can actually influence the behaviour of other elements, whereas `inline` elements do not.

See Also:

[MDN Documentation on Inline Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente)

[MDN Documentation on Block-level Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below jsfiddle

```css
#s1 {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
#s2 {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span id="s1"> span 1 </span>
<br>
<br>
<span id="s2"> span 2 </span>
    
    <p id="s2"> p 3 </p>
```

p and div elements are block level elements where span is an inline element and hence margin on span wont work.